# PyQT5 - Change value of other cells when ComboBox is checked of Unchecked

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I am using QTableView to display Pandas.Thank to the codes from StackOverFlow, I can do it.

I want to update the value of the cell on the right of a ComboBox when I check or uncheck some values of the ComboBox but I am new to PyQt5 and I don't know how to do.

When I select 'A' => the cell on the right will be 'A', then I check 'B' => the cell on the right will be 'A,B'. If I deselect A => the cell on the right will be 'B'

I have been searching but I cant not find a solution.
I really need your help.

This is what I am trying to do.

[image: Please click here to view]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

dept_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self._data.iat[index.row(), self._data.shape[1]-1] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])
            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])


class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._changed = False
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.checked_item=[]
        
        for i in range(len(dept_list)):
            self.addItem(dept_list[i])
            self.setItemChecked(i, False)


    def setItemChecked(self, index, checked=False):
        item = self.model().item(index, self.modelColumn())  # QStandardItem object

        if checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)

        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            if item.text() in self.checked_item:


                self.checked_item.remove(item.text())
            print(self.checked_item)

        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.checked_item.append(item.text())
            print(self.checked_item)
        self._changed = True
        
        self.check_items()

    def hidePopup(self):
        if not self._changed:
            super().hidePopup()
        self._changed = False


    def item_checked(self, index):
  
        # getting item at index
        item = self.model().item(index, 0)
  
        # return true if checked else false
        return item.checkState() == Qt.Checked
    
    def check_items(self):
        # blank list
        checkedItems = []
  
        # traversing the items
        for i in range(self.count()):
  
            # if item is checked add it to the list
            if self.item_checked(i):
                checkedItems.append(i)
                # checkedItems.append(self.model().item(i, 0).text())
  
        # call this method
        self.update_labels(checkedItems)
  
    # method to update the label
    def update_labels(self, item_list):
  
        n = ''
        count = 0
  
        # traversing the list
        for i in item_list:
  
            # if count value is 0 don't add comma
            if count == 0:
                n += ' % s' % i
            # else value is greater then 0
            # add comma
            else:
                n += ', % s' % i
  
            # increment count
            count += 1
  
  
        # loop
        for i in range(self.count()):
  
            # getting label
            text_label = self.model().item(i, 0).text()
  
            # default state
            if text_label.find('-') >= 0:
                text_label = text_label.split('-')[0]
  
            # shows the selected items
            item_new_text_label = text_label + ',' + n
  
           # setting text to combo box
            self.setItemText(i, item_new_text_label)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.combo_box_list=[]
        import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_excel(r"E:\092021-12 2022 1001.xlsx", skiprows=7)

        # data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 9, 2], [1, 0, -1], [3, 5, 2], [3, 3, 2], [5, 8, 9],],
        #                     columns=["A", "B", "C"],
        #                     index=["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3", "Row 4", "Row 5"],)

        df['Allocation Selection'] = ''
        df['Allocation']=''

        self.model = TableModel(df)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        # combo = CheckableComboBox()
        # for i in range(len(dept_list)):
        #     combo.addItem(dept_list[i])
        #     combo.setItemChecked(i, False)

        for i in range(df.shape[0]):
            combo = CheckableComboBox()
            self.combo_box_list.append(combo)
            # pix = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
            # combo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(lambda txt, pix=pix: self.tableView.model().setData(QModelIndex(pix), txt))
            self.table.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(i, df.shape[1] - 2), combo)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 200)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: How is the checkbox filled and shown? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: QTableView uses a model to represent its data. The key method to try and understand is https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data. If the `role` parameter there is `Qt::EditRole` this will result in a change of the data in position corresponding to the `index` parameter. You have to intercept that and then find its row and then find a cell in the same row but in a different column, and then change that. It is non-trivial.

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using QTableView to display a pandas dataframe. In this case it should be quite simple. You need to use the signal that comes from the QComboBox when an item is selected - probably `currentIndexChanged()`. You need to connect this to a function that will identify which items in your QComboBox are checked, and from this build the string that will go into the dataframe at the right place. Once the dataframe is updated, your QTableView should update to display the new cell of the dataframe.  Without knowing more about your exact setup (the checkable combobox) I can't be more specific.

Edit: Here is a working solution. The first step was to make the combobox aware of what row it is in - in this case I just passed the row number as a variable to the combobox on creation. It's a quick and dirty way to do it - it would be better to find the row of the table that the widget is in dynamically. The second step is to define a custom signal which passes the row and the checked item list to a function in the main class which updates the dataframe at that row with the new checked list.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

dept_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self._data.iat[index.row(), self._data.shape[1]-1] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])
            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])


class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    
    check_changed = pyqtSignal(int, list)

    def __init__(self, row):
        super().__init__()
        self._changed = False
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.checked_item=[]
        
        self.row = row

        for i in range(len(dept_list)):
            self.addItem(dept_list[i])
            self.setItemChecked(i, False)


    def setItemChecked(self, index, checked=False):
        item = self.model().item(index, self.modelColumn())  # QStandardItem object

        if checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)

        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            if item.text() in self.checked_item:


                self.checked_item.remove(item.text())
            print(self.checked_item)

        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.checked_item.append(item.text())
            print(self.checked_item)
        self._changed = True
        
        self.check_changed.emit(self.row, self.checked_item)

        self.check_items()

    def hidePopup(self):
        if not self._changed:
            super().hidePopup()
        self._changed = False


    def item_checked(self, index):
  
        # getting item at index
        item = self.model().item(index, 0)
  
        # return true if checked else false
        return item.checkState() == Qt.Checked
    
    def check_items(self):
        # blank list
        checkedItems = []
  
        # traversing the items
        for i in range(self.count()):
  
            # if item is checked add it to the list
            if self.item_checked(i):
                checkedItems.append(i)
                # checkedItems.append(self.model().item(i, 0).text())
  
        # call this method
        self.update_labels(checkedItems)
  
    # method to update the label
    def update_labels(self, item_list):
  
        n = ''
        count = 0
  
        # traversing the list
        for i in item_list:
  
            # if count value is 0 don't add comma
            if count == 0:
                n += ' % s' % i
            # else value is greater then 0
            # add comma
            else:
                n += ', % s' % i
  
            # increment count
            count += 1
  
  
        # loop
        for i in range(self.count()):
  
            # getting label
            text_label = self.model().item(i, 0).text()
  
            # default state
            if text_label.find('-') >= 0:
                text_label = text_label.split('-')[0]
  
            # shows the selected items
            item_new_text_label = text_label + ',' + n
  
           # setting text to combo box
            self.setItemText(i, item_new_text_label)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.combo_box_list=[]
        import pandas as pd
        #df = pd.read_excel(r"E:\092021-12 2022 1001.xlsx", skiprows=7)

        self.df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 9, 2], [1, 0, -1], [3, 5, 2], [3, 3, 2], [5, 8, 9],],
                            columns=["A", "B", "C"])

        self.df['Allocation Selection'] = ''
        self.df['Allocation']=''

        self.model = TableModel(self.df)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        for i in range(self.df.shape[0]):
            combo = CheckableComboBox(i)
            combo.check_changed.connect(self.update_df)
            self.combo_box_list.append(combo)
            self.table.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(i, self.df.shape[1] - 2), combo)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 400, 200)

    def update_df(self, row, checked):
        print(row, checked)
        self.df.at[row,'Allocation'] = checked


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: in the CheckableComboBox i have self.checked_item =[] to store checked items. But I dont know how to update Pandas.

Comment: See my edit for working solutuon. Note there is a bug in your code currently that changes the combobox text, I didn't deal with this.